# Recursively Nested Components with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, recursion

I'm trying to set up a parent-child hierarchy here are the relevant component definitions - I've simplified them to just show the structure of the hierarchy.

**RootComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
    <ComponentA></ComponentA>
</template>
```

**ComponentA.vue**

```html
<template>
    <!--...-->
    <ComponentB></ComponentB>
</template>
```

**ComponentB.vue**

```html
<template>
    <!--Some standard html tags-->
    <ComponentA></ComponentA>
    <!--...-->
    <ComponentC></ComponentC>
</template>
```

**ComponentC.vue**

```html
<template>
    <!--Some standard HTML tags-->
    <ComponentD></ComponentD>
</template>
```

The problem is that `ComponentA` within `ComponentB` is not rendered and the following error message is displayed in the console:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

The top-level instance of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` render correctly it is only the nested `ComponentA` one level down that does not render.

All of the components are created using the `Vue.extend()` method and have a `name` property defined on them. The components are imported by a `components:` property

ComponentA imports `ComponentB`

ComponentB imports `ComponentA` and `ComponentC`

**Edit**

**Component A Importing**

```js
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB.vue"
export default Vue.extend({
    name: "ComponentA",
    //...
    components: {
        ComponentB
    }
})
```

**Component B Importing**

```js
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA.vue"
import ComponentC from "./ComponentC.vue"
export default Vue.extend({
    name: "ComponentB",
    //...
    components: {
        ComponentA,
        ComponentC
    }
})
```

**Expected HTML Structure Rendered**

```html
<ComponentA>
    <ComponentB>
        <ComponentA>
            <ComponentB>
                <ComponentC></ComponentC>
            </ComponentB>
        </ComponentA>
        <ComponentC></ComponentC>
    </ComponentB>
</ComponentA>
```

**Actual HTML Structure Rendered**

```html
<ComponentA>
    <ComponentB>
        <!--ComponentA is missing here-->
        <ComponentC></ComponentC>
    </ComponentB>
</ComponentA>
```

I've spent hours searching online for solutions but can't find any that solve the issue. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to import within the components:{} ?
`components: {
  ComponentA: () => import('./ComponentA .vue')
}`

Comment: [Circular References Between Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)

Comment: @Shamsail Looks like that fixes it (at least I get a new probably unrelated error and the nested component renders) thanks! Interesting that I didn't get the error message described at that Circular References link